# md5sum or sha1sum of legitmate microsoft system files

Tags: windows, security, domain-name-system, anti-virus, malware

Is there a database or repository of the legitimate checksums for Microsoft system files? We think we have a 0day on DNS for Windows 2003 SP2 using IRC for command and control. (Latest McAfee does not see an issue). I want to compare our customer's dns.exe and associated DLLs with the real ones. (I will grab a fresh SP2 and hotfixed system to do this, but wonder how to do this in future without needed to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [System File Checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker)? It is designed to scan Windows sytem files and replace the "bad" ones. It's pretty easy to run from the command-line:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: SFC, IIRC, compares the files to the ones on the original install disc and will therefore have different checksums/modification dates/file sizes/etc for any updated file. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this utility (I'm not a Windows guy), but will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that Windows file protection was on and run the system file checker (SFC) [see this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193) for the registry entries to check and SFC/WFP options.  Newer versions of windows verify that the exe/DLL for OS files is signed by microsoft before loading.